# Share VPN connection established with Cisco VPN Client on a MacBook?

Tags: networking, vpn

Is it possible to share my VPN connection established with a Cisco VPN client to other devices via network sharing on my MacBook?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Go into System Preferences, select Sharing, then choose Internet Sharing.  When you click on the dropdown next to "Share your connection from:" the VPN connections will be in the list as well as any physical or wireless connections.  As an example everything in the list that starts with HMA is a VPN connection (I named them that way):
[image]

Comment: This does not work for me. If i connect via cisco vpn client no connection occures inside the dropdown-menu.

Comment: yes, do you have a solution now?